# How to get most recent entry with Repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm stuck on a pretty easy thing with Doctrine2 , I can't figure out how to retrieve last entry of an Entity with my findByDate method from the repository.
I wasn't able to find how to do it in Doctrine documentation or google...

Comment: You can also try the max(id) function

Answer (score 11):

You must do a query that order by date, and return the first :

```
class MyEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  function getLastEntity() {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')->
       orderBy('e.date', 'DESC')->
       setMaxResults(1)->
       getQuery()->
       getOneOrNullResult();      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$date = new \Datetime();

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$lastEntity = $em
                 ->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')
                 ->findBy(array('date' => $date->format('Y-m-d')));
```

Providing that the field in MySQL is stored as a `date`.

Comment: this is filtering by date, but I think the OP wanted to get the latest entry (i.e. the first result when sorted by date DESC).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `findBy()` method and passed the second parameter to what you want to order by. Say in your case `id`. `findBy([], ['id' => 'DESC'])`.
I hope it helps other people facing the same problem.
[Doctrine Querying by simple conditions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.17/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)